# python multiprocessing import

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm writing an add-on for a programme that uses a Python framework that doesn't have the multiprocessing module, which I really need for this add-on.

I tried including the module in a the path, but get an

```
ImportError: No module named multiprocessing.process
```

process.py is there, but is this error being caused by the whole module not being added to the path properly?

Comment: What's `sys.path` at the time of `import`, and where (what directory) does the `multiprocessing` package reside?

Comment: It is `multiprocessing.Process`. `Process` is a class

Comment: Also keep in mind that imports (and other things) are cap-sensitive.

Comment: Many thanks Alex, that was the clue I needed: very stupidly I had been trying to add the wrong path to sys.path, I was effectively adding full filepath to the module rather than to the directory it sat in, all worked afterwards.  The thing that was throwing me off was still seeing the error message `No module named _multiprocessing`, it turns out the workaround here [link]https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1504 works.